# Need Regex for to match special situations

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm desperately searching for regular expressions that match these scenarios:

1) Match alternating chars

I've a string like "This is my foobababababaf string" - and I want to match "babababa"

Only thing I know is the length of the fragment to search - I don't know what chars/digits that might be - but they are alternating.

I've really no clue where to start :(

2) Match combined groups

In a string like "This is my foobaafoobaaaooo string" - and I want to match "aaaooo". Like in 1) I don't know what chars/digits that might be. I only know that they will appear in two groups.

I experimented using (.)\1\1\1(.)\1\1\1 and things like this...

Comment: What language or regex flavor are you working with?

Comment: I'm currently working with PHP using preg_match / preg_match_all so it's al PCRE (PCRE Library Version => 7.8 2008-09-05).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this is what you want.

For alternating characters:

```
(?=(.)(?!\1)(.))(?:\1\2){2,}
```

`\0` will be the entire alternating sequence, `\1` and `\2` are the two (distinct) alternating characters.

For run of N and M characters, possibly separated by other characters (replace `N` and `M` with numbers here):

```
(?=(.))\1{N}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{M}
```

`\0` will be entire match, including infix. `\1` is the character repeated (at least) `N` times, `\2` is the character repeated (at least) `M` times.

Here's a test harness in Java.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Regex3 {
    static String runNrunM(int N, int M) {
        return "(?=(.))\\1{N}.*?(?=(?!\\1)(.))\\2{M}"
            .replace("N", String.valueOf(N))
            .replace("M", String.valueOf(M));
    }
    static void dumpMatches(String text, String pattern) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
        System.out.println(text + " <- " + pattern);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("  match");
            for (int g = 0; g <= m.groupCount(); g++) {
                System.out.format("    %d: [%s]%n", g, m.group(g));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
            "foobababababaf foobaafoobaaaooo",
            "xxyyyy axxayyyya zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
        };
        for (String test : tests) {
            dumpMatches(test, "(?=(.)(?!\\1)(.))(?:\\1\\2){2,}");
        }
        for (String test : tests) {
            dumpMatches(test, runNrunM(3, 3));
        }
        for (String test : tests) {
            dumpMatches(test, runNrunM(2, 4));
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
foobababababaf foobaafoobaaaooo <- (?=(.)(?!\1)(.))(?:\1\2){2,}
  match
    0: [bababababa]
    1: [b]
    2: [a]
xxyyyy axxayyyya zzzzzzzzzzzzzz <- (?=(.)(?!\1)(.))(?:\1\2){2,}
foobababababaf foobaafoobaaaooo <- (?=(.))\1{3}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{3}
  match
    0: [aaaooo]
    1: [a]
    2: [o]
xxyyyy axxayyyya zzzzzzzzzzzzzz <- (?=(.))\1{3}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{3}
  match
    0: [yyyy axxayyyya zzz]
    1: [y]
    2: [z]
foobababababaf foobaafoobaaaooo <- (?=(.))\1{2}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{4}
xxyyyy axxayyyya zzzzzzzzzzzzzz <- (?=(.))\1{2}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{4}
  match
    0: [xxyyyy]
    1: [x]
    2: [y]
  match
    0: [xxayyyy]
    1: [x]
    2: [y]
```

---

#### Explanation

- `(?=(.)(?!\1)(.))(?:\1\2){2,}` has two parts

  - `(?=(.)(?!\1)(.))` establishes `\1` and `\2` using lookahead

    - Nested negative lookahead ensures that `\1` != `\2`
    - Using lookahead to capture lets `\0` have the entire match (instead of just the "tail" end)
  - `(?:\1\2){2,}` captures the `\1\2` sequence, which must repeat at least twice.
- `(?=(.))\1{N}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{M}` has three parts

  - `(?=(.))\1{N}` captures `\1` in a lookahead, and then match it `N` times

    - Using lookahead to capture means the repetition can be `N` instead of `N-1`
  - `.*?` allows an infix to separate the two runs, reluctant to keep it as short as possible
  - `(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{M}`

    - Similar to first part
    - Nested negative lookahead ensures that `\1` != `\2`

The run regex will match longer runs, e.g. `run(2,2)` matches `"xxxyyy"`:

```
xxxyyy <- (?=(.))\1{2}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{2}
  match
    0: [xxxyy]
    1: [x]
    2: [y]
```

Also, it does not allow overlapping matches. That is, there is only one `run(2,3)` in `"xx11yyy222"`.

```
xx11yyy222 <- (?=(.))\1{2}.*?(?=(?!\1)(.))\2{3}
  match
    0: [xx11yyy]
    1: [x]
    2: [y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use perl/PCRE:

1. `(.{2})\1+` or `((.)(?!\2)(.))\1+`. Second regex prevents matching things like `oooo`.

**UPD**: Then 2. will be `((.)\2{N}).*?((?!\2)(.)\4{M})`. Remove `(?!\2)` if you want to get matches like `oooaoooo` and replace N and M with n-1 and m-1.

Comment: I need a regex that matches combination of groups - for example a group of n identical chars followed by a group of m identical chars.

The simpler pattern would look like this: xxyyyy - but it might also be xxayyyy or xxaaayyyy - so that both groups are seperated by arbitrary characters.

Comment: Updated. Hope I understood you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works for the first one...

```
((.)(.))(\2\3)+
```

Comment: Can you please give a short explanation of this regex?

Comment: Yep. ((.)(.)) matches 2 characters next to each other (whilst also looking suggestive). (\2\3) matches the same 2 characters again, and the + says this must happen 1 or more times. Looking at it, you may be able to ditch the outer brackets in the first set and change the back references accordingly.

Comment: But it looks more suggestive with the outer parentheses, so please leave them in.

Comment: For some reason, with the outer parens there it reminds me of Japanese video games.

Answer (score 0):

Examples in javascript

```
a = "This is my foobababababaf string"

console.log(a.replace(/(.)(.)(\1\2)+/, "<<$&>>"))

a = "This is my foobaafoobaaaooo string"

console.log(a.replace(/(.)\1+(.)\2+/, "<<$&>>"))
```

Comment: Both of those regex can match runs of a single character, like `aaaaaa`; I don't think the OP wants that.